# How to add CSS (w/ query results) into dynamic reply_html_page in Prolog?

Tags: html, prolog, swi-prolog

I'm really having a hard time transitioning to coding in Prolog. When a user submits data from a web page, then I try to return a new page showing the results of a query based on what the user submitted. Here is what I have so far.

**Edit**: (Replaced code snipped for complete source)

```
:- use_module(library(http/thread_httpd)).
:- use_module(library(http/http_dispatch)).
:- use_module(library(http/http_error)).
:- use_module(library(http/html_write)).
:- use_module(library(http/http_client)).
:- use_module(library(http/http_parameters)).
:- use_module(library(http/html_head)).
:- use_module(library(http/http_server_files)).

:- use_module(parts, [part/4]).

:- http_handler(root(.), main_query, []).
:- http_handler(root(search), search, []).
:- http_handler(root(search), part_results, []).

http:location(css, root(css), []).

server(Port) :-
    http_server(http_dispatch, [port(Port)]).

:- multifile
    user:body//2.

user:body(part_style, Body) -->
    html(body([
        div([id(top)], ['Parts']),
        div(id(content), Body)
        ])).

main_query(Request) :-
    reply_html_page(
        part_style,
        title('Beta Query'),
        [\page_content(Request)]).

page_content(_Request) -->
    {  http_link_to_id(search, [], Ref) },
    html([ \html_requires(css('part-style.css')),
        form([id(search), action='/search', method='POST'], [
        div([id(search_table)], [
            div([class(search_cell)], [
                label([for=part], ' '),
                select([name=part], \parts)
            ]),
            div([class(search_cell)], [
                label([for=major], ' '),
                select([name=major], \majors)
            ]),
            div([class(search_cell)], [
                label([for=minor], ' '),
                select([name=minor], \minors)
            ]),
            p([], [
                input([name=submit, class="button", type=submit,
                    value='Search'], [])
            ])
        ])
        ])
    ]).

css(URL) -->
    html_post(css,
        link([ type('text/css'),
        rel('stylesheet'),
        href(URL)
        ])).

part_results(Request) :-
    reply_html_page(part_style,
        [title('Part Results'),
        \css('part-style.css'),
        \html_receive(css)]).
%       \query_part).
% having trouble truing query_part into DCG.
query_part(Request) :-
    member(method(post), Request), !,
    http_read_data(Request, Data, []),
    format('Content-type: text/html~n~n', []),
    format('<p>', []),                                        
    memberchk(part=Part, Data),
    memberchk(major=M, Data),
    memberchk(minor=I, Data),
    atom_number(M, Major),
    atom_number(I, Minor),
    findall(p(Part, Major, Minor, Desc),
        part(Part, Major, Minor, Desc), Descriptions),
    maplist(desc, Descriptions),  
    format('</p>'),
    format('<a href="http://localhost:8000" class="button">Back</a>').

desc(p(P,M,I,D)) :- format("~q ~q:~q - ~q</br>", [P,M,I,D]).

parts -->
    { findall(P, part(P, Major, Minor, Desc), Parts),
        sort(Parts, Sorted) },
        options(Sorted).

majors -->
    { findall(M, part(Part, M, Minor, Desc), Majors),
        sort(Majors, Sorted) },
        options(Sorted).

minors -->
    { findall(I, part(Part, Major, I, Desc), Minors),
        sort(Minors, Sorted) },
        options(Sorted).

options([]) --> [].
options([O|Os]) -->
    html(option([value=O], O)),
    options(Os).
```

Trying to define this query_part/1 into a DCG is giving me lots of headaches. Originally the handler directly called the part_query/1, but now there's a part_results rule that calls DCG's and query_part us passed a Request arg. I've been trying to read up on DCG's, but still not quite understanding them other than they are supposed to make writing rules easier, nor do I understand how to use {}'s with them, which I think I need to do. (However, the DCG itself is out of the scope of this question since it covers so much and I can continue trying to understand it elsewhere). So I'm still trying to get the CSS with query results into the reply page.

Currently, the CSS is showing up in the body of the HTML.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have several comments about this:

## Immediate solution

First, a **solution** for your task: To **post** the resource, simply use the `css//1` nonterminal in `part_results/1`:

```
part_results(Request) :-
    reply_html_page(part_style,
                    [title('Part Results'),
                     \css('myfile.css'),
                     \html_receive(css)],
                    \query_part).
```

This is enough to obtain what you want. You use `css//1` in exactly the same way you use any other nonterminal in the HTTP framework, using the `(\)/1` espace syntax.

## Different solution

A *different* solution to obtain almost *the same result* is to use `html_requires//1`:

```
part_results(Request) :-
    reply_html_page(part_style,
                    [title('Part Results'),
                     \html_requires(css('my-style.css'))],
                    \query_part).
```

This is a library predicate from `library(http/html_head)`, and does essentially what you are doing *manually* currently.

Note that you need to use `library(http/http_server_files)` to define the required locations to resource files. In the case of CSS files, the predefined location is `root(css)`, so you need to put your css file in `css/*`, which is different from what you are doing manually.

## Why only body?

In your original example, why was only the **body** emitted? Answer: *Because you did not emit anything else*.

Note that instead of using `reply_html_page/3`, you can simply **emit the whole page yourself on current output**. This of course requires that you *emit everything you want*, not only the body.

## General advice

Next time, please post a **self-contained example**, not only partial snippets, to make it easier for others to try your code.

This means:

- include **all necessary libraries**
- give instructions how to **start the server**
- show how to **access the server**
- etc.

Comment: I edited the OP with complete code (guess I thought before I was doing only what was relevant, then noticed it wasn't). Also, is one solution preferred over the other (e.g., is one more flexible)? Currently, the CSS shows up in the body of the HTML.

Comment: Your edit has changed the scope of the question, please don't do that! Please re-edit your question to ask what it previously asked, because the answer answers what you originally asked. Please file separate questions for your other concerns. Regarding the different approaches, this would also be worth a question in itself. The differences are roughly: Outputting plain text is straight-forward but error prone; using the HTML infrastructure requires learning the infrastructure; using `html_requires//1` is easy, and using post/receive is most flexible and general, since you can post any time.

Comment: Changed the scope? I reread before the edit and I'm still after the same goal, trying to get a reply page to incorporate CSS. Don't quite see how this has changed from the OP. I'm still trying to combine CSS into an html reply, and still stuck trying to defined the DCG query_part/1. This is all the same. The majority of what I did was to add the complete source like you asked.

Comment: You have added: "I've been trying to read up on DCG's, but still not quite understanding them other than they are supposed to make writing rules easier, nor do I understand how to use {}'s with them, which I think I need to do.", which is a much more general question than "How to add CSS into dynamic reply_html_page in Prolog?", which is what you originally asked. Please retain the original scope of the question, since changing it may render existing answers inapplicable. Better ask a new question for your other concerns! See [tag:dcg] and [resources](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/dcg/info)!

Comment: I keep seeing solutions using DCG's, which is why I mention them (since usually the query is within a DCG), but again, the DCG is not my question. It's always been CSS and the query results into the reply page.

Comment: OK, please let us handle these concerns separately. For this question, please simply forget everything about `query_part/1` (remove its definition and call), and apply the changes I outlined in my answer. This gives you a blank or almost blank page, but you see that the CSS is there. Then, file a new question on how to extend the DCG so that is describes the page you want. You need to treat these aspects systematically, and provide a shortest working example that illustrates your problem so that others can try your code and post the necessary changes more easily.

Comment: Right, I do see a page that is empty with a head and a body. And the CSS line is within the body. I had removed it while trying to see what was happening. About the example, kind of lost on the working example because that's exactly what I did by adding the complete "shortest working" example, that you asked for previously. Am I missing something? Do I need to add the database? Before that I just included the snippit of code showing only the rules I thought be used in order to accomplish this.l

Comment: Cont'd: I'll work through the query outside of this question, got a new book on the way that has a section on DCG's.

Comment: Please use the example code I show to add the CSS line to the **head** (second argument) instead of the body. You definitely didn't include the *shortest* example that shows this problem, since all the parts, majors and minors, and several other predicates including in fact the whole page content have nothing to do with including CSS in the header. Ideally, you will trim such examples down to a single predicate that does not behave as expected in future questions. In this case, a single call of `reply_html_page/3` that uses no other predicates would suffice to discuss and correct the issue.

Comment: I have it as you have suggested, but do see that it isn't in my example of which I have tried so many combinations. Either way, I'm going to go ahead and mark this to close it down, I'm sure it's close enough, but I just don't thing we're communicating here. This isn't working for me, but thanks for the effort.